# Populating a column in R with a given logic

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe in R and I want to destroy it.

Comment: What do you mean by destroy it? If you want to remove the dataframe from global environment and your dataframe is called `df` you can do `rm(df)` to delete it. Is that what you want? Also this is completely different from your original question that you had posted earlier. In such cases it is advisable to ask a new question instead of editing the current question.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new dataframe with the exact same dimensions then assign its value to your old dataframe. Something like

```
old_df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
```

would work